# How to convert a IFS formula with an ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Could you please help me to convert this IFS formula in an ARRAYFORMULA?

The formula is:
=SUMIFS('CHICKEN USA'!$GF$11:$GF$1100;'CHICKEN USA'!$AO$11:$AO$1100;$B6;'CHICKEN USA'!$AP$11:$AP$1100;$C6;'CHICKEN USA'!$BP$11:$BP$1100;$D6;'CHICKEN USA'!$BU$11:$BU$1100;"First Quality")

Thank you for your help

Comment: use sumif and concatenate `&` the conditions.

Comment: Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like a sample spreadsheet with dummy data so that the community can have a better understanding of your current data and the actual expected result. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.